# Flush Enterprise library cache block data of one ASP .NET web site from another

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, caching, enterprise-library, flush

I have two ASP .NET Web sites using one same static instance of a cache manager.  The first web site fetches data from a database and caches it using the forth mentioned cache manager object.

My problem is that i am unable to flush this cached data from my second Web site using the same cache manager static object.  Is there anything wrong in trying to doing so and what are the possible solutions to this problem?  (Any documentation material on the subject would be appreciated)

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Create 2 instances of the cache manager
- Configure your web sites to use different application pools

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Create a method in `Site 2` that can be access via `www.Site2Domain.com/clearECache`

```
public void ClearECache()
        {
            try
            {
                CacheManagerSettings conf = (CacheManagerSettings)ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create()
                    .GetSection(CacheManagerSettings.SectionName);

                conf.CacheManagers.ForEach(delegate(CacheManagerDataBase cache)
                {
                    CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(cache.Name).Flush();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw

            }

        }
```

Now from `Site 1` do a `HttpRequest/WebRequest` to the `site 1` URL